# MYSQL Query locking up server

Tags: php, mysql

When trying to execute this query my mysql server cpu usage goes to 100% and the page just stalls. I setup an index on (Client_Code, Date_Time, Time_Stamp, Activity_Code, Employee_Name, ID_Transaction) it doesn't seem to help. What steps can I go about next to fix this issue? Also there is already one index on the database if that matters any. Thanks

Here is what this query does

Database info

```
ID_Transaction | Client_Code | Employee_Name | Date_Time |Time_Stamp| Activity_Code  
1               | 00001       |  Eric         |   11/15/10|   7:30AM |     00023  
2               | 00001       |  Jerry        |   11/15/10|   8:30AM |     00033  
3               | 00002       |  Amy          |   11/15/10|   9:45AM |    00034  
4               | 00003       | Jim           |   11/15/10|   10:30AM |   00063  
5               | 00003       | Ryan          |   11/15/10 |   12:00PM |   00063  
6               | 00003       | bill          |   11/14/10 |   1:00pm  |  00054    
7               | 00004       | Jim           |   11/15/10 |   1:00pm  | 00045  
8               | 00005       | Jim           | 11/15/10| 10:00 AM| 00045
```

The query takes the info above and counts it like so. By the most recent entry for each client_code. In this case the query would look like this. After php.

```
Jerry = 1    
2               | 00001       |  Jerry        |   11/15/10|   8:30AM |     00033     
Amy = 1   
3               | 00002       |  Amy          |   11/15/10|   9:45AM |    00034   
Ryan = 1  
5               | 00003       | Ryan          |   11/15/10 |   12:00PM |   00063  
Jim = 2  
7               | 00004       | Jim           |   11/15/10 |   1:00pm  | 00045  
8               | 00005       | Jim  | 11/15/10| 10:00 AM| 00045   



 $sql = "SELECT m.Employee_Name, count(m.ID_Transaction)   
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Client_Code FROM Transaction)   
 md JOIN Transaction m ON    
m.ID_Transaction = ( SELECT  
ID_Transaction FROM Transaction mi  
WHERE mi.Client_Code = md.Client_Code AND Date_Time=CURdate() AND Time_Stamp!='' AND 
 Activity_Code!='000001'  
ORDER BY m.Employee_Name DESC, mi.Client_Code  DESC, mi.Date_Time DESC,  
mi.ID_Transaction DESC LIMIT 1 )  
group by m.Employee_Name";
```

Is there a better way to write this query so it doesnt bog down my system? The query works fine with 10 database entries but it locks my server up when the database has 300,000 entries.

Thanks
Eric

```
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table       | type   | possible_keys          | key          | key_len | ref            | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2>  | ALL    | [NULL]                 | [NULL]       | [NULL]  | [NULL]         |    8 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | m           | index  | [NULL]                 | search index | 924     | [NULL]         |   21 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer  |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | mi          | ref    | search index,secondary | search index | 18      | md.Client_Code |    3 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED            | Transaction | index  | [NULL]                 | secondary    | 918     | [NULL]         |   21 |    38.10 | Using index                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------------+--------+------------------------+--------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Run an `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` in front of that query and post the output.  That will give us details on your indexing.

Comment: post your explain plan, show indexes from <all tables used in query> and describe <all tables used in your query>

Comment: If your Transaction table has 300,000 entries, how many are returned based on the where statement in your sub-select on this table?  If it is a lot, you most likely want to do a join instead of using sub select.  In general you'll probably want to do a join anyway, but specifically when there are large numbers of rows, subselect can get really slow.

Comment: What hardware specs do you have for this MYSQL server? How much ram? etc

Comment: 500mb ram 2ghz cpu. Its a virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

What about going with multiple `GROUP BY`'s instead of the all the sub queries to simplify things.... something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Transaction WHERE Date_Time=CURdate() AND Time_Stamp!='' AND Activity_Code != '000001' GROUP BY Client_Code, Employee_Name
```

If I'm understanding your query correctly then something like this would solve the issues and prevent the need for sub queries.

Comment: how about they normalise for starters

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely want to do a join instead of a sub select.

Also, how many records are you viewing? Is pagination and using limit out of the question?

If you set up your initial query modified with inner/outer joins as a view and it doesn't crash, you'll be one step closer. Once the view is set up, you'll be able to use a much less complicated select statement - potentially paginated.

Comment: I was under the impression that views didn't add much, if any optimization in MySQL.  Sure they might make some queries look simpler, but i've heard often times they can reduce performance.  Is this just one of those old MySQL-isms that has changed in recent years, or is it still true?

Comment: Views will index, so once it runs once, it will be optimized to run again and not have to explicitly rebuild the data. If the query is large and needs to be explicitly built each time it will take more resources.

Comment: MySQL does not [support materialized views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html).  Sure, it can cache part of the query, but it's not building indexes or anything for the view.  If you want to do that you're better off building a summary table and keeping it up to date with multiple triggers...